# C# - FRENCH - VisualStudio WebBrowser with Google API DirectionsService.Route()

Tags: javascript, c#

hello all I created a TestProject to use the Google MAP Direction.Route() on a WebBrowser in visual studio 2015... But i have one problem.. The 'route' dont work with my 'WebBrowser' on VisualStudio2015 but it's working in 'Google Chrome','Internet Explorer' and 'FireFox'.

I dont understand why.

The problem  ( Left with 'WebBrowser' Right 'Google chrome, firefox, internet explorer' ) :

Picture : My problem :

[image]

The code HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
  html { height: 100%; }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
  #map { height: 100%;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <!-- Test placement des points Panterga et chez moi --> 
        <script>
            function PutPoints()
            {
                var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
                var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
                {
                    center: "Paris, fr",
                    zoom: 7
                });

                directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
                directionsService.route(
                    { origin: "Paris, fr", destination: "Marseille, fr", travelMode: 'DRIVING' },
                    function (reponse, result) { directionsDisplay.setDirections(reponse); }
                    );
            }
        </script>
        <script async defer 
                src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.33&signed_in=true&language=fr&callback=PutPoints'>
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: does webbrowser support defer and async on scripts?

Comment: i suppose, the map load but the route not.

Comment: you might want to add visual studio tag and why is that c# tag there?

Comment: Because i use this code with Visual studio 2015 c# on WebBrowser in Visual studio.

Comment: Pete, thank you. The WebControl dont work in async mode.